# In Windows, what are the purposes of file extensions?

Tags: windows, file-association, file-extension, file-format, file-types

As far as I know, in Linux filename extensions don't have any special meaning to the operating system. It helps users to identify the file, of course, but the OS itself simply does not care about it (right?).

I've heard that this is not the case in Windows, but I don't really understand - **does filename extensions serve any purpose beyond human assistance in Windows?**

I'm concerned about that because I'm a software developer who needs to build software that interact with user inputted files, and therefore I need to verify the validity of these files. With Linux, I'm 100% certain I cannot verify the files through the filename, as it can be anything. Is that the same for Windows?

Comment: I would say your initial premise is incorrect - though there is never anything preventing a file having a completely inappropriate extension, they are there as a guide to which app is capable of handling that type. This is a system-level association, Mac, nix or Win. The app attempting to open the file, however, must test its validity.

Comment: Extensions exist to give the user an idea of what type of file it is supposed to be and so that the OS may use the appropriate application to attempt to open the file. Having a specific extension does *not* mean that file conforms to the format its extension claims it is.

Comment: So extensions always work as "helpers"? I mean, the OS never considers it has any intrinsic meaning, but just assumes it is what is says it is and then starts testing the file's validity from that?

Comment: @yyyyyyyan The OS does not do any testing for the file's validity. As Tetsujin said, it's up to the application that opens the file to test its validity. All the extension means to the OS is that when a user double-clicks on the file, it will attempt to open that file in the application that is associated with that extension. For example, I can rename test.txt to test.mp3 and then double-click it, the OS will attempt to open that file in my media player. The media player will then throw an error saying it can't play the file.

Comment: @SamForbis Thanks, I get it! But is this the same in Linux and Windows? Is there any significant difference between one and another or am I just tripping?

Comment: linux uses file signatures to ID filetype ... also called "magic numbers" ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures .... https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: See Wikipedia [Filename extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) and [List of filename extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by Sam in the comments, the extension is there so that Windows knows which application to use when opening the file. So yes, it does serve a purpose to Windows.

The list of extensions linked to specific applications can be generated with dism:

```
Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:"D:\Associations.xml"
```

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
  <Association Identifier=".bmp" ProgId="AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc" ApplicationName="Photos" />
  <Association Identifier=".c" ProgId="Applications\Notepad.exe" ApplicationName="Notepad" />
  <Association Identifier=".conf" ProgId="Applications\NOTEPAD.EXE" ApplicationName="Notepad" />
```

There's also info about all kinds of extensions inside the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

[image: registry]

There is no validation testing performed by Windows. Applications might do that, or they might just inform you that they cannot read the file if it's not "valid".